# How to dynamically add RowValidationErrorTemplate to a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I want to add a RowValidationErrorTemplate to a DataGrid using C# code (i.e. not in XAML).
The corresponding XAML:

```
<DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid Margin="0,-2,0,-2" 
              ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
            <Ellipse StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                     Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
            <TextBlock Text="!" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                       FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
```

If you wonder the reason behind this, here is my situation:

1. I have several **UserControls** that inherit from a .cs code.
2. Each **UserControl** contains a **DataGrid** that has: **RowValidationErrorTemplate**, EventHandlers, Validation Methods, ... etc.

I moved the EventHandlers to the base class, now I'm looking for a way to move the last part of my validation code to the base class.

Comment: Why not creating your own control that inherits from DataGrid?

Comment: @Isma, do you mean XAML inheritance? This is a very complex topic that I try to avoid. That's why my UserControls inherit from .cs code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `XamlReader.Parse` method to dynamically create a `ControlTemplate`:

```
string xaml = "<ControlTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\"><Grid Margin=\"0,-2,0,-2\" ToolTip=\"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}\"><Ellipse StrokeThickness=\"0\" Fill=\"Red\" Width=\"{TemplateBinding FontSize}\" Height=\"{TemplateBinding FontSize}\" /><TextBlock Text=\"!\" FontSize=\"{TemplateBinding FontSize}\" FontWeight=\"Bold\" Foreground=\"White\" HorizontalAlignment=\"Center\" /></Grid></ControlTemplate>";
dataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as ControlTemplate;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is the only way to edit the `ControlTemplate` is by using XAML format? Are there no classes and properties corresponding to the XAML?

Comment: Yes, there is the FrameworkElementFactory but using it is a deprecated way to programmatically create templates as stated on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelementfactory(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks. And they state "The recommended way to programmatically create a template is to load XAML from a string or a memory stream using the Load method of the XamlReader class."